# undefined вместо картинки, несколько картинок - Unexpected field

Tags: typescript, nestjs

```
    @Post('upload')
    @HttpCode(200)
    @UseInterceptors(FileInterceptor('files'))
    async uploadFiles(@UploadedFiles() files: Array<Express.Multer.File>) {
        console.log(files)
    }
```

Если отправляю картинку в files, то лог выводит undefined, если отправляю больше двух, то возвращает:

```
 {
    "statusCode": 400,
    "message": "Unexpected field",
    "error": "Bad Request"
}
```